# Weierstrass function

Tags: plotting, functions, fractals

I am trying to create plot of the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) in Mathematica.

I wonder if it's possible, when I define this function as

```
f[x_]:=Sum[(1/2)^n * Cos[3^n * Pi * x], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

I'll be grateful if someone can help me solve this problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A computer is a finite machine and there is a limit to how well you can visually explore such functions.  Perhaps it will give enough of a impression to sum only a few terms.  Even 5 terms exceeds the monitor's ability to display all the turns.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[Sum[(1/2)^n*Cos[3^n*Pi*x], {n, 0, k}], {k, {1, 2, 5}}],
 {x, 0, 3},
 PlotStyle -> Table[Thickness[0.0085 - 0.002 k], {k, 3}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can explore the functions dynamically with `Manipulate`.  You can have controls that determine how many terms and zoom in on the graph.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[Sum[(1/2)^n*Cos[3^n*Pi*x], {n, 0, terms}]],
  {x, Clip[x0 - Exp@zoom, {0, 3}], Clip[x0 + Exp@zoom, {0, 3}]},
  PlotStyle -> Table[Thickness[0.0085 - 0.002 k], {k, 3}],
  GridLines -> {{x0}, {}}
  ],
 {{terms, 2}, 1, 10, 1},
 {{x0, 1.5}, 0.4, 2.6},
 {{zoom, Log[3.]}, -6., Log[3.]}]
```

Comment: Choose the proper Weierstrass function you seek by typing `?? Weier*`.  Then select the function you seek and plot it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The function the OP is talking about is different from all of those.

Comment: So why is "Weierstrass" in the title?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Weierstrass studied (and wrote about) more than one kind of function.  Two are famous, the ones already in *Mathematica* that are related to elliptic functions and elliptic curves, and the ones the OP is talking about that are continuous everywhere and differentiable nowhere.

Comment: Ah... thanks very much.  I know about the "classical" Weierstrass functions, but not the class described in this problem.  The question poser might have helped us by mentioning the point in your note.